# How to debug SIGTRAP using gdb?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gdb, assembly-trap

My own program uses SIGTRAP signal. I want to use gdb to debug my program. 
However, when the SIGTRAP is raised in my program, gdb cannot go into my trap handler.

How to single step into my trap handler?

Comment: try `handle SIGTRAP pass nostop`, though I think having a `SIGTRAP` handler could be problematic (GDB also complains about it).

Comment: Thanks! I tried it, but it doesn't work. I still cannot single step into the trap handler.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it will work for you, but try to use `sigaction` to turn off your signal handler (within your signal handler), and than raise SIGTRAP again.

That should raise the signal to the OS, which will call the debugger (hopefully).
afterwards use `sigaction` again to register you own handler.